# Short film about a woman solo parenting a boy who move into a house with a witch

Tags: story-identification, short-film

Back in the late 1970s I saw a short film in elementary school (classroom film projector) where a woman solo-parenting an only son (who is maybe about 8 or 10 years old) moves into a creepy old house in which a witch lives… or at least an old woman who everyone thinks is a witch. I think the film is mostly in black and white, except in a few moments when the mom and her kid eat pancakes made by the old woman: with each bite bright, quasi-psychedelic and quite magical spots and patterns brighten up the world accompanied my cheerful sounds. The moral of the film was about confronting one's expectations of others.

These three characters are white. If I recall correctly, the film is probably around 10 to 15 minutes, and looked to be professionally produced, rather than a home-film project.

Comment: Is the title supposed to end with "at least one witch"?

Comment: And, for the sake of being on-topic, was she a witch? Or at least it's left a possibility that she is?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots " with each bite bright, quasi-psychedelic and quite magical spots and patterns brighten up the world accompanied my cheerful sounds" was diegetic, so I would say **Yes, she was a witch (meaning *magical*)** although not meaning "nasty".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably *[Winter of the Witch](https://archive.org/details/WinterOfTheWitchShortStoryFilm1980)*

> A young boy and his mother move from the city into a country house already occupied by a 300 year old unemployed witch who makes happiness-inducing pancakes with the hope that she will be able to regain her rightful occupation

It's not black-and-white, but otherwise matches.

Found with a search for `black and white short film witch pancakes`, which brought up [this blog entry](https://forgottenstoriesweb.wordpress.com/2017/10/04/old-black-witch/), primarily about the original book, *Old Black Witch*.

Comment: The pancake images and music happen at about 14:40.

Comment: Welp, that was it, and 40+ years does interesting things to memories. :) Thank yoU!